# Which directory permission are needed to read the content of a file?

Tags: permissions

I have read permission a a file.

Which permissions *and why* are required _in the `/` and in the `/path` directories to be able to `cat /path/file.txt` ?

Comment: I posted an answer, because I need a 'why' , not only the information. Please review my question if not exact or incomplete

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to access to any file located under the /path directory, the user must have the x (execute) permission granted for each of the directories in the path (this including root).

The reason for this is that *cat* will use the [open](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html) system call. System call which :
can fail with the following errors:

> EACCES (…) or search permission is denied for one of the directories
> in the path prefix of pathname, (…)

Note that this page invites you to learn more about [path resolution](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/path_resolution.7.html) in Linux.

Answer (score 1):

I can summarize what I learned from suggested question

For what I understand

- 'r' is 'read the list of file names in the directory'
- 'x' is 'do something which the content of the directory'

To read a file *content* i *do not* need the 'r' permission on directory because I know the filename so I do not need to read the directory listing

To read a file *content* i stille need the 'x' permission on directory because it's required to resolve the path to the file *contents*

What causes confusion in me the difference from *file names* and *file contents*. The first is *in the directory* the second is *in the files*. But to access a file i need 'x' because i need to access the directory itself anyway.

Comment: "because it's required to do anything" -> because it is required to resolve the path.